# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 beta install failed, now won't uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Against the advice of one of my buddies, I installed the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 beta on my dev box at work. Or rather, I tried to. I used the web installer, but halfway through the install it failed.

When I try to uninstall or repair it, I keep getting dialogs saying that different files aren't available and I need to insert various CDs. Trying to do a fresh install from the ISO version yields the same result.

Any suggestions?

Josh

Edit: I'm running Windows 7 64 bit. The files seem to be different every time I try to repair or uninstall the SP, but last time the dialog was asking me to insert the visual studio 2010 prerequisites disk. Another time it was complaining about the F# runtime. I'll try again and post a few specific file names, but I don't think the files are the issue so much as the botched install.

Comment: What are these "different files" and "various CDs"? Maybe more info will help... (P.S.: I'm not sure if this is a great question for SO...)

Comment: Edited post with a little more detail, and I'll collect more info in a few minutes. If this is not an appropriate post, my bad. There were lots of posts about installation issues with the VS 2010 beta, so it seemed like it would be OK.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I disagree that this is not appropriate for SO -- questions about IDEs are definitely on-topic.

Comment: @Kirk: Huh ok, I wasn't too sure... I thought since this wasn't related to programming then it might not be great for SO, but I didn't vote to close or anything like that, thankfully. :)

Comment: @JoshEarl: Hm... the files are different every time? That's funny... seems like this'll be an interesting problem!

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. The dialog gives me the option to ignore the message, and if I do that, I'll get another popup in a few seconds asking about another file. I'm leaning toward uninstalling VS completely and trying to do a clean install. That would take a long time, though, and it seems like it would have a good chance of ending in failure.

Comment: I installed the final release of VS2010 SP1 and have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The installer was looking for files in my `Temp` directory, since that's where the web installer initially put them. It was still looking there, even when I was running the ISO installer. Every time the dialog popped up, I was able to browse to the file on the ISO. It would ask for the file again, and then it would accept it. Very strange, but it eventually worked. The reapplication took about an hour to complete. Hope this helps someone else!